# ubuntu 18.04 cannot update

Tags: updates, update-manager

When I try to update my 18.04 with command `sudo apt update`, I have the following results and I do not know how to resolve. Can someone help me with it? Thank you.

```
Hit:1 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [2,801 B]    
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [65.4 kB]   
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [69.9 kB]
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Get:10 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [50.1 kB]
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't see why you can't update. Yes, you can.

With that out of the way, you've added a PPA for ubuntu-tweak, that has no packages for 18.04. Remove it with

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:trebelnik-stefina/ubuntu-tweak
```

PS: In case `ppa-purge` isn't installed, install it.